# How to operate multidimensional features in SVM or use multidimensional features to train model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

If I have this input:

```
"a1,b1,c1,d1;A1,B1,C1,D1;α1,β1,γ1,θ1;Label1"  
"... ... "  
"an,bn,cn,dn;An,Bn,Cn,Dn;αn,βn,γn,θn;Labelx"
```

Array expression：

```
[
 [[a1,b1,c1,d1],[A1,B1,C1,D1],[α1,β1,γ1,θ1],[Label1]], 
 ... ... ... ... 
 [[an,bn,cn,dn],[An,Bn,Cn,Dn],[αn,βn,γn,θn],[Labelx]]
                                                     ]
```

Instance:

```
[... ... ... ...
 [[58.32,453.65,980.50,540.23],[774.40,428.79,1101.96,719.79],[503.70,624.76,1128.00,1064.26],[1]], 
 [[0,0,0,0],[871.05,478.17,1109.37,698.36],[868.63,647.56,1189.92,1040.80],[1]],
 [[169.34,43.41,324.46,187.96],[50.24,37.84,342.39,515.21],[0,0,0,0],[0]]]
```

Like this:
There are 3 rectangles,and the label means intersect,contain or some other.
I want to use 3 or N features to train a model by SVM.
And I just learn the "**python Iris SVM**" code.What should I do?

**The Opinion:**
this is my try：

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
mport matplotlib as mpl
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def label_type(s):
    it = {b'Situation_1': 0, b'Situation_2': 1, b'Unknown': 2}
    return it[s]


path = 'C:/Users/SEARECLUSE/Desktop/MNIST_DATASET/temp_test.data' 
data = np.loadtxt(path, dtype=list, delimiter=';', converters={3: 
label_type})

x, y = np.split((data), (3,), axis=1)
x = x[:, :3]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=1, 
train_size=0.6)

clf = svm.SVC(C=0.8, kernel='rbf', gamma=20, decision_function_shape='ovr')
clf.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Report Error:

```
Line: clf.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

If I try to convert the data:

```
x, y = np.split(float(data), (3,), axis=1)
```

Report Error:

```
Line: x, y = np.split(float(data), (3,), axis=1)

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Could you please include the line at which the error was raised?

Comment: I have add the line information already.

Comment: I suspect you can't take `float` of `data` because `data` isn't a length 1 array, and therefore it can't be converted to a python scalar (i.e. a `float`)  use `data.astype('float')`, a numpy method.

Comment: It doesn't work,maybe because the symbol ',' in data like[0,0,0,0] can't be converted to be float type?

Comment: Would flattening the input features be a valid option for you?

Comment: Surely I want a one-dimensional input,but it seems hard to flatten the rectangle into a single point..I dont know whether I can get one function to do this.

Comment: @YuanChu please be sure about your data before you go for flattening. It may solve the problem of not getting error but it may not get you good model. Please understand the data and why data is representing that way. Dig up a little. It won't hurt!

Answer (score 0):

SVMs were not initially designed to handle multidimensional data. I suggest you flatten your input features:

```
x, y = np.split((data), (3,), axis=1)
x = x[:, :3]

# flatten the features
x = np.reshape(x,(len(x),-1))

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=1, 
train_size=0.6)

clf = svm.SVC(C=0.8, kernel='rbf', gamma=20, decision_function_shape='ovr')
clf.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I would change my idea to finish my project.

Answer (score -1):

I have few questions before I go for an answer:

**Q1.** What kind of data you are using to train SVM model. Is it image data? If image data then, is it RGB data? The way you explained you data it seems you are intended to do image classification using SVM. Correct me if I am wrong.

**Assumption**
Let say you have image data. Then please convert to gray scale. Then you try to convert entire data into numpy array. check `numpy` module to find how to do that.

Once you data become `numpy` array then you can apply your model.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: A1:I want to find a strong feature to explain my label.But now,I only have 3 weak features,and I want to find a relationship to make 3 to 1 by using SVM.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `[a1,b1,c1,d1]` is one feature against which you want find if that explains the labels correctly? and `[A1,B1,C1,D1]` so on...

Comment: I think use one single feature to do posture classification is inefficient,so I try to make some weak features.And I try to do graphic intersection identify as my simple step.

Comment: That's mean    [ [Feature 1-1]，[Feature 1-2]，[Feature 1-3] ，[label 1]] ,because it hard to get[[Feature 1],[label 1] ]

Comment: is this the features belongs to movement in three directions like tensors?

Comment: No,It's more like cropping Image.Learn features from the local,and detect the whole.

Comment: Then it won't hurt applying each cropping image features to explain target label. Later you can try ensemble.